# Forming a likelihood (and/or conditional distribution of a random variable) from an implicit function

Tags: distributions, bayesian, likelihood

EDIT: This is now written in a more minimalist form for statistics/econometrics audience rather than the more Bayesian learning or Bayesian Nash Equililbrium style.

My problem involves finding the likelihood given an observable tied down by an implicit function, which will not have any closed form solution.  To set notation and the random variables:

- Unobserved value: $Y = \bar{Y} + \epsilon_Y$, where $\epsilon_Y \sim N(0,\sigma^2_Y)$
- An unobserved value based on $Y$, which is $y = Y + \epsilon = \bar{Y} + \epsilon_Y + \epsilon$.  where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2_y)$
- Another unobserved value (independent of $Y$), $x = \bar{x} + \nu$, where $\nu \sim N(0,\sigma^2_x)$
- All of the noise terms, $\epsilon, \epsilon_Y,$ and $\nu$ are independent
- Finally, assume there exists a $F(y,x,p)$ with reasonable convexity, monotonicity, invertibility, etc. but which does not have an explicit formula.  Furthermore, the following must hold for any $y, x$ and $p$.
  $$
    F(y, x, p) = 0
    $$
- $p$ is the only observable

Let's say we can form a joint distribution: $Z \equiv \begin{bmatrix} y & x & Y & p \end{bmatrix}$.  Then partition this as $Z \equiv \begin{bmatrix}
Z_1 & 
Z_2
\end{bmatrix}$ where $Z_1 \equiv \begin{bmatrix}y & x & Y\end{bmatrix}$ and $Z_2 \equiv \begin{bmatrix}p\end{bmatrix}$.

**Question:**
Given knowledge of $F(\cdot)$, and an observation of $p$, what is the likelihood of $y, x$ and $Y$?  i.e.,
$$
L(Y, y, x |p)
$$

From the connection between densities and likelihood, isn't the likelihood the same thing (or at least proportional to) the conditional distribution of:
$
Z_1  \,|\, Z_2 
$, which can be calculated from the joint distribution of $Z$?

---

A few things:

- Note that there are two unobserved values here, $y$ and $x$.  This means that the likelihood for $y$ is non-degenerate.

  - i.e. if there was no $x$, then the $F(y,p) = 0$ could be inverted to find $y$ exactly.  Then the likelihood of $Y$ is easy.
  - Hence, I don't think this problem can be reduced to anything much simpler
- I have successfully done this in closed form with a linear $F(\cdot)$ using the projection theorem, but in general I have a non-linear $F(\cdot)$ (which is actually determined by this likelihood after I combine with a prior on $Y,y,x$.  This is a tricky Bayesian Learning Problem with a fixed-point).
- Hence, numerical methods will almost certainly be necessary, but I can't design them until I have at least some implicit function for the likelihood based on derivatives, inverses, etc. of the likelihood.

---

**For the Linear Case**

To help understand the setup, let me sketch out the approach for the case where $F(\cdot)$ is affine.

(1) Assume that $F(x,y,p) = -p + c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 y$ for some $c_1,c_2, c_3$.  Then rearranging and inverting the $F(x,y,p) = 0$ condition you get
$$p = c_1 + c_2 x + c_3 y
$$
(2) This can also be written as a constant term and then some constants on the shocks.
$$
p = \left[c_1 + c_2 \bar{x} + c_3 \bar{Y}\right] + c_2 \nu + c_3 \epsilon_Y + c_3 \epsilon
$$

(3) From here, note that $p$ is written in terms of constants and the shocks, given $\epsilon, \epsilon_Y,$ and $\nu$.  We also have $Y = \bar{Y} + \epsilon_Y$, $y = \bar{Y} + \epsilon_Y + \epsilon$, and $x = \bar{x} + \nu$

So using the distributions of the shocks, we can form a joint distribution of $\begin{bmatrix} y & x & Y & p \end{bmatrix}$ using the variance and covariances of all of these normal variables, and due to linearity it remains gaussian.  I won't write out all those steps as they are standard but tedious

Lets say that we can write out the joint distribution partitioned as,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
Z_1 \\
Z_2
\end{bmatrix} \sim N\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu_1 \\ \mu_2\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}\Sigma_{11} & \Sigma_{12}\\ \Sigma_{21} & \Sigma_{22}\end{bmatrix} \right)
$$
where $Z_1 \equiv \begin{bmatrix}y & x & Y\end{bmatrix}$ and $Z_2 \equiv \begin{bmatrix}p\end{bmatrix}$.

(4) Finally, you can use the conditional distribution of the multivariate normal from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions  The general formula is,
$$
Z_1  \,|\, Z_2 \sim N\left( \mu_1 + \Sigma_{12} {\Sigma_{22}}^{-1} \left( Z_2 - \mu_2 \right) , \Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12}{\Sigma_{22}}^{-1}\Sigma_{21} \right)
$$

(5) We are done as $Z_2 = p$ is the observable and we can calculate the means and variances of the joint distribution.
One difficulty: If the joint distribution is non-Gaussian (and it would be for a general $F$), then there may be some sort of projection theorem required for more generality to solve this problem.

Comment: You're using $\bar Y$ do denote an unobservable quantity (in this case a parameter); if you must do so (rather than follow more usual convention of using bars for sample averages), it's best to highlight that you've done so. You should probably define what "hidden private values" are.

Comment: Sorry, this is the standard convention for bayesian learning with multiple agents.  Let me reorganize this to be more consistent with how the statistics crew thinks about this.

Comment: @Glen_b The text has been updated and simplified to make this easier for a non-learning audience.

Comment: I don't mind notation outside the usual stats convention (as you say, some areas of work do things different ways, especially in ML but also in other areas), as long as it's not likely to mislead almost everyone else (i.e. as long as the main convention-breaking aspects of notation are clearly defined, even if they're fairly conventional in the scope of the question).

Comment: Thanks for reading.  Is the new write-up clear now?

Comment: Clearer, at least. Here $\perp$ is intended to mean "independent", "uncorrelated" or something else?

Comment: Changed to drop the notation.

Comment: If it meant uncorrelated rather than independent (which I suspected, and why I asked for clarification), then certainly the likelihood cannot be specified until you specify the dependence structure.

Comment: Thanks.  Changed to independent.  There is nothing at all ``sketchy'' going on with the noise terms, so hopefully that is sufficient.

Comment: Are you asking for $Pr(p | Y, y, x)$ which would be $Pr(p | Y, y, x, F(x,y,p)=0)$?  That is my understanding of likelihood of parameters.  Do we know anything about the distribution of $p$?  If my assumption is wrong, could you say exactly what you mean by the likelihood of $Y, y, x$.

Comment: @jlimahaverford thanks.  There is a connection between the likelihood and the probability for all the normal reasons, and the $Pr(p|Y,y,x)$ may be it (or close).  I don't know about your other notation, but it looks right.  We don't know anything else about $p$ (except that it has to fulfill the $F(x,y,y)=0$ function and that $p$ is observable).  I am pretty sure I have posed this question correctly (as I can solve it for a linear $F$)

Comment: @jlperla No problem!  What I mean to ask is, you said you want some, at least implicit, function for **the** likelihood function $L(Y, y, x|p)$.  I am asking if you can define what you mean by **the** likelihood function explicitly.  Perhaps if you demonstrated what you did in the linear case, we would be able to more easily help you with the generalization.  What feels like a much more comfortable quantity is $P(Y, y, x | \bar{Y}, p)$

Comment: @jlimahaverford  Thanks, an I see what you are saying.  I believe that the likelihood here is exactly what you are writing down.  You definitely know $\bar{Y}$ and the other parameters of the random variable.

Comment: @jlimahaverford I added a note in this to the description.  Using the connection between the likelihood and the pdf, I think it is closer to the $Pr(p | Y, y, x)$ with a constraint that you had before.

Comment: But without any information about how $p$ is chosen other than that it must satisfy $F(y,x,p) = 0$ it is impossible to determine that probability.  At this point I would like to see what you did in the linear case.  That will make everything much clearer.  In particular get to the likelihood function in the linear case.

Comment: @jlimahaverford See my sketch of the solution to the linear model.  I don't do all of the covariances, but those are very standard.

Comment: So in the linear case $Pr(p| y, x)$ is one if $p=c_1 + c_2x + c_3y$ and zero else wise.  Something tells me this is not the value you are interested in.  I think you're interested in $Pr(x, y| p)$

Comment: Notice at the end of your example you're discussing $Z_1 | Z_2 = x,y | p$.

Comment: @jlimahaverford  Thanks.  I got rid of the probability comment and changed it over to the condition distribution more precisely.  Hopefully this is correct now.